# How does arithmetic or elementary function operation latency scales with the number of bits?

Tags: performance, floating-point, cpu-architecture, word-size

Notice that the ratio between 64-bit and 32-bit float ops is different on different hardware. For example, recently NVidia improved 64-bit performance while 32-bit remained unchanged. That made me curious: given sufficiently wide datapath, what are the factors that determine by how much certain floating point ops have to be when you double the number of bits?

For the purpose of this question assume that you can significantly increase the width of your datapath when you double the number of bits. Not unlimited (otherwise a lookup table would theoretically be possible for any arithmetic function), but wide enough to perform arithmetic operation in parallel on independent bits. Given that, by what factor would doubling word size would slow down arithmetic operations +,*,/? And what about built-in elementary functions such as log,exp,sin,atan?

EDIT:

Let me explain more clear what I am asking here.

First of all, it's known that if theoretically one has unlimited circuitry/area one can compute any mathematical operation on N bit input(s) in O(log N). All one has to do is to create a huge hash table of size 2^N (for 1-operand functions such as sin(x)) or 2^(2*N) (for 2-operand functions) and lookup the desired value using the input as the hash key. Needless to say this is completely impractical, and I am not interested in an answer like that. However, that shows that one cannot theoretically prove that any operation would necessarily require more than O(log N) time, given arbitrary width of the datapath.

Second, it's also known that Omega(log N) is a lower bound for even relatively simple operation such as an adder. This has to do with the depth of dependencies between the output bits, and therefore the depth of the circuit.

The question really is: given a reasonable bound on the size of the circuit (say, no more than polynomial(N) gates) what would be the asymptotic behavior of the latency of the optimal circuit implementing arithmetic and elementary function operations?

The answer is known to be O(log N) for adder, realized by carry lookahead adder. I don't know the answer for multiplication, but suspect one can implement it as a O(log N) circuit as well because multiplication boils down to const time booleans followed by adding multiple operands, and extending carry lookahead to a multi-operand adder doesn't seem too difficult.

I have no clue what would be the asymptotic for division and square root.

I am also curious about common elementary functions, such as log, exp, sin, etc.

Comment: If you can double your datapath and have enough space to simply create all the necessary hardware to carry out math operations, there theoretically would be no performance slowdown by increasing the number of bits. You must establish some constraint for there to be a feasible solution. Likely, Nvidia moved to doing more 64-bit math with native 64-bit HW instead of 32-bit microcode. Would explain why 64-bit floating point operations made gains while 32-bit remained unchanged. They finally caught up with the times.

Comment: Assuming identical throughput for the basic operations in both single precision and double precision, the throughput of a single-precision transcendental function is typically 1.1x to 1.5x that of the corresponding double-precision function. This is mostly driven by the use of more complex core approximations, e.g. higher order polynomials, needed for double precision. There may also be additional instructions in the double-precision version due to higher cost of loading wider constants.

Comment: @iheanyi: NVIDIA GPUs have had native double precision hardware support since shipping compute capability 1.3 parts some seven years ago. In the GPU space, double precision throughput is used for product differentiation based on use cases and price points. Most consumer parts (GeForce) have low double-precision throughput, most compute-only parts (Tesla) have high double-precision throughput.

Comment: @iheanyi: it cannot be const time, there is a known lower bound log(N) for any N-bit operation. For example [carry lookahead adder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-lookahead_adder) is known to have asymptotically optimal performance, although in reality O(sqrt(N)) adders perform just as well in much smaller area. Thus for datapath of any width there ought to be some lower bound on the depth of circuit. The question is: what are those lower bounds for common operations?

Comment: @Michael It is not clear what you are driving at (not to me, anyway). Yes, latency will go up when the bit-width of operands to arithmetic operations is considered, but in terms of throughput that can be overcome by deeper pipelining and increased parallelism. Making the question answerable will require some stated constraints, such as "using the same silicon real estate".

Comment: NVidia artificially limits double-precision performance on consumer-grade GPUs (to make them impractical for things like scientific computing, where they'd rather you buy the more expensive Tesla products), so changes in performance don't really tell you anything about the performance characteristics of the actual hardware.  They might've just made a firmware change to reduce how much time the GPU deliberately wastes while doing double calculations.

Comment: If you check the overview of NVIDIA GPUs on Wikipedia, for example, (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) you will find that most consumer cards are based on chip versions that are entirely different from those used for Tesla. Those chip versions only include a small amount of double precision compute units, which reduces silicon area and thus cost, which is important in the consumer *graphics* market, which has no need for double-precision computation. It would not be economical to "defeature", via SW, a large chip with full double-precision throughput for sale in a $150 consumer graphics card.

Comment: Multiplication is the big issue. For doubling precision, C[1]:C[2]=A[1]:A[2] * B[1]B[2] translates into C[1] = A[1]*B[1]; C[2]=A[1]*B[2]+A[2}*B[1]. Double precision FP more than doubles the size of the significand  (53 bits vs. 24 bits). Things get worse if one implements single-rounding fused MADD since correct rounding of the add portion may require a full 106 bit (vs. 48 bit) product if the addend is significantly smaller in magnitude than the product. (For double rounding only the zero/non-zero nature of the LSbits is required beyond the 54-bit/25-bit product.)

Answer (score 1):

There are two dimensions in which increasing logic complexity will affect circuit delay. One is impact on pipeline stages, where one or more combinational delays will be "critical paths" constraining the minimum clock period.  Almost arbitrarily (albeit with varying amounts of work), you can take a complex circuit and pipeline it in any number of stages.  More stages will chop up the logic more, increasing the latency in cycles but also reducing the min clock period, which increases throughput.  Note that as you increase stages, you run into diminishing returns, because the pipeline registers have constant overhead.  Also, more pipeline stages means that dependent instructions have to wait longer to get their inputs, although that doesn't affect GPUs so much because of the high thread parallelism.

Just to get it out of the way, I'll mention that increasing your circuit area will always indirectly affect performance.  Larger circuits mean more complex placement and routing, and that's going to mean that combinational delays will not scale linearly with the number of logic gates.  We'll ignore that for now.

Doubling the datapath width for some things won't have any impact on combinational delay.  For instance, if you have a bit-wise AND operation, every bit is computed independently.  So in the abstract, doubling your datapath width will not affect your cycle time.

Now, you're asking about floating point, but a floating point pipeline is going to be composed of integer blocks that do things like add (and subtract), multiply, and shift.  I'm going based on memory here, so someone may need to correct me, but here goes.

A carry look-ahead add or sub unit will generally increase logarithmically with the number of bits, so doubling the datapath width will (again, ignoring the impact of placement and routing) only increase delay a little bit.

IIRC, a barrel shifter has the same growth rate as add/sub.

A multiplier will increase linearly with width because it's more or less a 2D array of full adders, but some optimizations can be made.  So if you double the datapath width, I think you'll double the circuit delay.  So in this case, you may want to pipeline your multiplier into two stages.